# JavaFX: Any possible reason why tableView.getSelectionModel().select(0) won't work?

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx, tableview, selectionmodel

Can you list possible reasons why calling `tableView.getSelectionModel().select(0);` on a `javafx.scene.control.TableView` named `tableView` won't work?

For this case, let's say I'm using `cellSelectionEnabled(false)` and `SelectionMode.SINGLE`, and `tableView.getItems()` returns a non-empty `FXCollections.observableArrayList`.

To be more precise, I'm looking for possible answers why there can be instances wherein calling `tableView.getSelectionModel().select(0);` from a method like `selectTableViewRow0()` won't work:

```
private void selectTableViewRow0(){
    tableView.getSelectionModel().select(0);
}
```

Any suggestion, guys?

**Edit:**
As mentioned in the comments below, calling `tableView.getSelectionModel().isSelected(0);` returns true. I'm guessing I can use reflection to call the code in TableView that highlights the selected row. The problem is I can't seem to find out which part of the TableView code I should call. I figured calling select(0) will lead to calling the following two lines internally. But after that there seems to be no code telling the TableView to highlight the selected row.

```
updateSelectedIndex(row);
focus(row, column);
```

Comment: Seems similar to [RT-30356 Selection bar in ListView not always displayed for a selected item](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-30356), but perhaps it's different.  Update your question to include full environment details and an [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Hi, I have already included the environment details. However, I can't seem to replicate the error using an ssce. It might be much to ask but can you/someone provide a workaround for selecting an item using reflections probably? Thanks.

Comment: I don't have any such workaround.

Comment: Alright thanks man. I'll try to update this post once my problem is solved.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to jewelsea and jhsheets for contributing. One reason I found for this problem is that when a similar scene comes into play, and then the old scene is not garbage collected, the old table view item (from the old scene) will be selected. Luckily, I found a related bug, which I can discuss if someone is interested.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        tableView.getSelectionModel().select(0);
    }
});
```

Comment: Will try. I'll comment after trying.

Comment: What happens if you call: tableView.getSelectionModel().isSelected(0) right after?  Is the result true?  Maybe it's not triggering because it thinks the row is already selected and not firing a change event.  Does tableView.getSelectionModel().clearAndSelect(0) work?

Comment: Will try. I'll comment after trying.

Comment: It turns out that tableView.getSelectionModel().isSelected(0) returns true after tableView.getSelectionModel().select(0); and tableView.getSelectionModel().clearAndSelect(0);. However, the selected row doesn't highlight. I'm guessing this has something to do with the TableView's skin?

Comment: Does the row highlight if you click on it?  Unless you changed something, highlighting should work.  Check to see if you're setting -fx-background-color anywhere in a CSS file or in a setStyle() method.  Check if you have any TableRowFactory classes, or if you're doing something weird in your CellValueFactory's.  You might want to try tableView.getSelectionModel().setSelectedIndex(0) as well; I've never used the select() method myself.  I'm not sure if select() does something weird like not trigger a table refresh to show the highlighted row.

Comment: Also, it can be difficult to tell when a row is highlighted on a TableView if the table view isn't focused.  Double-check that you're not just mistaken about the row being highlighted.

Comment: Yes, the row highlights when I click on it. I didn't do any styling though. Will try setSelectedIndex and tableView.requestFocus() as well and then I'll comment for updates. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi, as checked, setSelectedIndex is not a method for getSelectionModel(), while requestFocus() showed that the row wasn't highlighted.

Comment: Looks like setSelectedIndex() is a protected method.  Sorry, all out of ideas.  Maybe file a bug report, or try using a different Java7 build.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Already filed a bug report for this. Although I don't know if they'll accept it without a short simple and compilable example. Also edited the question fyi.